# Сайт не открывается при (80%)работающей админке

Tags: php, dns

Может кто подскажет. Суть вопроса такая.

На новый выделенный сервер, перенесена БД и файлы.

Часть сайта работает - админка, но тоже не вся, через раз. Сам сайт не открывается. (DNS не переписываю т.к. не уверен в работоспособности сайта)

Доступ к сайту можно сделать через файлег hosts прописать ip и домен.

Суть в следующем, может ли действительно играть роль то, что NS сервера не прописаны и сайт некорректно отображается. Или это, как я и считаю, отмаза глупых людей?

> `Если подключиться по адресу *.*.*.* через telnet, а потом  отправить запрос  GET http://site.ru/ HTTP/1.0 - выдается содержимое главной страницы, как  оно и должно быть.  Так что сам сайт по-видимому работоспособен, а проблема именно в  NS-серверах.`

Это их ответ, на что я не верю. Причем тут связь NS серверов и сайта, который как зеркало перенесен с хостинга на отдельный сервер. ***Или я гоню?***

Дополню.
При таком раскладе работает админка

> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php
>   .html .php

При таком не работают скрипты в Html

> AddHandler x-httpd-php
>   .html .php

Вот скрин хоста

42[image]

Вот .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .php
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error_403.html
#php_value error_reporting 0

RewriteEngine On

# другие адреса главной страницы - кидаем на фасад

# все несуществующие адреса - тоже на фасад
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^user(.*)$ /user.php [L]
```

*Про telnet у них открывался рабочий сайт. Как не знаю, спрашивать не стал.т.е. если даже я вызываю ошибку на сайте я её типа вижу,а у них все по прежнему*

Comment: ОЧЕНЬ прошу глупые комменты не писать - удаляю сразу!

Только по существу и конкретика!

Comment: В php/js случайно нет кусков проверки IP/хоста? Меня virtuemart этой хренью радует постоянно. Опять же, могут быть жестко прописаны какие-то пути. Может что-то в .htaccess быть. В любом случае ищите жесткие пути - как серверные (`/var/www/...`), так и внешние (`http://site.ru/...`).

Comment: Все это прописано на новые адреса и пути.

Если бы не было прописано то админка бы не работала.

Вопрос именно и звучит в том что "Те кто мне предложил вариант что дело в NS серверах" он прав или нет. Я Считаю что нет! Эта строчка никак не повлияет на работу сайта на новом серваке.

В скриптах все пути уже заменены на новые, на сайте тоже в конфиге все заменено.  Вопрос в другом. :)

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема решилась просто переписью DNS и настройки сервера под нужды.

А телнет так и выдавал ошибки.

Answer (score 5):

Как вы проверяете, что сайт не работает? И что в логах?

Ответ саппорта по сути верный. Если при запросе напрямую через `telnet` веб-сервер отдает корректный HTML - значит он рабочий. Во всяком случае по запрошенному URL.

А почему сайт может не работать из-за DNS, можно придумать много причин. Самое простое, если он обращается к каким-либо своим веб-сервисам(хотя в этом случае, `telnet` тоже выдал бы ошибку)

PS

> Это их ответ, на что я не верю.

Чему вы не верите? Не верите их словам или `telnet`'у?

Comment: мы отправляем запрос на IP адрес. подключаемся. а потом отправляем запрос GET http://site.ru/ HTTP/1.0 

Скорее всего в файле HOSTS того кто проверяет не прописан IP и этот домен. ВОт и отдается содержимое реального сайта!

ТАк что да Я не ВЕРЮ ни им ни телнету в данном случае.

Comment: У меня почему-то при telnet'e на IP сервера ничего не отдается. Так что вопрос по прежнему открыт.

Comment: Да не нужен никакой ip в hosts, вы что не знаете как HTTP работает?

Предположим, если ваш сайт ya.ru и ip вашего нового сервера 213.180.204.3 (реальный ip яндекса) то сделав:

    $ telnet 213.180.204.3 80
    Trying 213.180.204.3...
    Connected to 213.180.204.3.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    GET / HTTP/1.0
    Host: ya.ru
    
    HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
    Server: nginx
    ...

Вы сделаете полноценный запрос к серверу без использования dns.

И еще логам своего сервера вы тоже не доверяете?

Comment: > У меня почему-то при telnet'e на IP сервера ничего не отдается. Так что вопрос по прежнему открыт.

Так с этого и надо было начинать. Только что значит ничего не отдается? Отваливается по таймауту? Если при этом пинг до сервера проходит, значит на сервере на 80 порту никто не слушает (веб-сервер выключен, настроен на другой порт, etc).